# Why is truncate a DDL statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

The table structure remains same after truncate statement and only records get deleted (with auto commit).  Then what is the reason that truncate is a DDL statement ?

Comment: [Why is truncate DDL?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36607/why-is-truncate-ddl)

Comment: I studied T-SQL fundamentals third edition written by Itzik Ben-Gan that TRUNCATE is a DML statement

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd add here some explanation:
 By default, when truncating a table , you are not just removing rows, you are implicitly telling Oracle Database to also perform the following tasks:

Deallocates all space used by the removed rows except that specified by the MINEXTENTS storage parameter

Sets the NEXT storage parameter to the size of the last extent removed from the segment by the truncation process

So, it changes the storage definitions  and changing the structure of the table by resetting the water high mark.

Also it can't be a DML ,right? 
Where clause can't be specified or comes along with DDL statement.  If truncate is a DML statement then Oracle would have allowed us to use truncate along with where clause.
Note: A WHERE clause in SQL specifies that a SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement should only affect rows that meet specified criteria.

Comment: Plus: no triggers are executed (before/after delete) and also the cached execution plan in library cached get invalidated.

Comment: Exactly, even cursor got effected by that truncate statement because of that library cache gets invalidated.

Comment: Why you said ` If truncate is a DML statement then Oracle would have allowed us to use truncate along with where clause.` ? can we use where clause with INSERT?

Comment: Though we cannot use where clause directly in insert we can use where clause along with 'insert...select' statement

Answer (score 11):

`TRUNCATE` resets the high water mark of the table, effectively eliminating all the previously existing rows. Treating it as a DDL statement allows it to be super-fast, as it allows it to function without retaining undo (rollback) information like DML statements.

Answer (score 9):

A simple practical explaination can be :

Truncate reinitializes the identity by making changes in data definition therefore it is **DDL**, whereas Delete only delete the records from the table and doesn't make any changes in its Definition that's why it is **DML**.

Like Create a Table **Names** and Insert Some Initial records.

[image: Created table Inserted Some Records]

Delete all records(Without where Clause) and Insert records again.
Identity is not reinitialized.

[image: Delete All Records and insert again]

Now Truncate Table and Reinsert the records.

[image: Truncate table and reinsert records]

Comment: The question is about Oracle, not SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

It's not a [secret](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/truncate-table.html#:%7E:text=TRUNCATE%20TABLE%20empties%20a%20table,DML%20method%20of%20deleting%20data.) that TRUNCATE TABLE works as a combo of DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE statements.
DROP TABLE (DDL) + CREATE TABLE (DDL) -> TRUNCATE TABLE (DDL)

---

Yes, it removes data, but it's just a result of DROP TABLE. **No DML at all.**
This answer looks simpler and quite obvious so I think it should be here.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).