# cannot use truncate inside stored procedure oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

hello i made a procedure to take record from table and insert it to other table then after table insertion i want to truncate the first table here's my code

```
create or replace 
procedure sp_getOldRecord
As
Begin
insert into T2
select *
from (select * from T1 order by time_stamp)
where rownum=1;

truncate table T1;
End;
```

but i get this error on the truncate line

```
Error(9,10): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TABLE" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; The symbol ":= was inserted before "TABLE" to continue.
```

here's a screenshot
[image]

Comment: That's because [TRUNCATE TABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059855/why-is-truncate-a-ddl-statement) is a DDL statement and therefore cannot be executed directly in PL/SQL. Try using [dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/lnpls/dynamic-sql.html#GUID-7E2F596F-9CA3-4DC8-8333-0C117962DB73).

Answer (score 0):

`truncate` is a DDL so you'll need dynamic SQL:

```
create or replace 
procedure sp_getOldRecord
As
Begin
insert into T2
select *
from (select * from T1 order by time_stamp)
where rownum=1;

execute immediate 'truncate table T1';            --> this
End;
```

---

Or, if table doesn't contain many rows, maybe you'd rather `delete` from it; it is a DML command and doesn't require dynamic SQL.

Though, as DDL implicitly commits, think twice whether that's what you really want to do because it'll also commit `insert into t2` *within the procedure*, so - if you wanted the caller to do that - you'd rather not truncate the table.